# Android awkward behavior

Tags: android, behavior

I'm making an app that creates new files, there's no problem when I name the files like this:

```
private String FILENAME = "myFilename";
```

but when I use a method to name the file, the compiler jumps straight to this line:

```
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

then to my class declaration:

```
public class AddUser extends Activity
```

And the application crashes.

This is what the log file says:

```
12-03 16:26:12.814: E/AndroidRuntime(20307): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 16:26:12.814: E/AndroidRuntime(20307): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.ProfileSaved}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 16:26:12.814: E/AndroidRuntime(20307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-03 16:26:12.814: E/AndroidRuntime(20307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-03 16:26:12.814: E/AndroidRuntime(20307):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
```

This is my file naming method:

```
int firstArray;
int nextArray;  

private String fileNamer(){

    File dataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    File fileDir = new File(dataDirectory, "data/com.myapp.app/files");

    String[] filenameArray = fileDir.list();

    Arrays.sort(filenameArray);

    if (filenameArray.length == 0){
        return "0";
    }

    if (filenameArray.length == 2500){
        return "too_many_items";
    }

    if (!filenameArray[0].equals("0")){
        return "0";
    }

    int arrayLength = filenameArray.length;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<arrayLength-1;){

        firstArray = Integer.parseInt(filenameArray[i]);
        nextArray = Integer.parseInt(filenameArray[i+1]);

        if (firstArray+1 == nextArray){
            i++;
        }
    }
    return Integer.toString(nextArray+1);
}
```

The method seems to be working fine but I just can't see why would it affect the rest of the program since all it does is to return a String?

Comment: Your code is buggy and you should read crash log carefuly instead of looking at wrong place. If you'd quote log cat correctly, we'd know where your `NullPointerException` crash occurs, but as for now, you have to check that yourself and then look at file and line mentioned there.

Comment: Updated the error log to the first five lines. If that's what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys thanks for your input.

I believe I finally got it right. First of all the method indeed was buggy but that wasn't really the issue, a good answer would've been something like:

"There IS a difference between a `String` and invoking a method that returns a `String` that is assigned to a variable, because in order to use the invoked `String` in another Class you'll probably need to set the variable as `static`. That's why the `String` is working and the 'method invoked' `String` not."

About the bugs in the code just in case someone is ever interested, the `if` in

```
if (firstArray+1 == nextArray)
```

needs the `else` in case there is an empty space between filenames, like `1, 3, 4` so the next file gets named `2`.

The other bug was that I was comparing filenames as `Strings` so when I sorted them, they were sorted as `1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

The solution I used was to add zeros to the beginning of the filenames like `0001, 0002,` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`if (filenameArray.length == 2500){` should be `if (filenameArray.length >= 2500){`, I suspect. But more importantly,

```
    for(i=0; i<arrayLength-1;){
        firstArray = Integer.parseInt(filenameArray[i]);
        nextArray = Integer.parseInt(filenameArray[i+1]);
```

will access `filenameArray[arrayLength]` which doesn't exist. I think you meant

```
    for(i=0; i<arrayLength-2;){
```

and you should also check that there are at least two elements in the array. That doesn't sound right, to me.

Comment: Thanks I changed it to >= but about the other code I had it like (i=0; i<=arrayLength-2;) before but I changed it to (i<arrayLength-1) and seems to work